# Set Default Windows Installer Disk

Tags: windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, windows-installer, installer

I was wondering if it was possible to set the default disk to be used my MSIs, E.G. Install to D:\Program Files by default rather than C:\Program Files, and, if it is possible, how to do so.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the default program installation directory in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/185414/how-can-i-change-the-default-program-installation-directory-in-windows-7), [Forcing programs to be installed to another drive](http://superuser.com/questions/755465/forcing-programs-to-be-installed-to-another-drive), [How do I install programs onto an alternate drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/74450/how-do-i-install-programs-onto-an-alternate-drive), [Installing Windows on one drive but Program Files on another](http://superuser.com/questions/268463) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps as below:

1. Start Registry Editor by entering “Regedit” in the search All programs.
2. Locate the following:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
3. Right click on the value named ProgramFilesDir & change the default value C:\Program Files to the path you want to install all your programs in.
4. Click OK and Exit.